# Detect text position in an image and crop it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, crop

I have this picture
[Text in an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFa6i.jpg)

I want to detect that text position, and crop the image focusing only at that text.

this my code:

```py
from PIL import Image 
# Opens a image in RGB mode 
im = Image.open(r"image.jpg") 
# Size of the image in pixels (size of orginal image) 
# (This is not mandatory) 
width, height = im.size 
print(im.size)
# Setting the points for cropped image 
left = 5
top = height / 4
right = 164
bottom = 3 * height / 4
# Cropped image of above dimension 
# (It will not change orginal image) 
im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 
# Shows the image in image viewer 
im1.save("new.jpg")
```

This code work fine, but the position of the text in the image not static.
I want the code automatically detect the position of the text then crop it.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the actual problem?

Comment: I tried split the image into (height/30) part (NOTE : 30 that the height of the box that can read the number in the image) than went inside 'for' loop and read them all, if the script find the number its break the loop.
But Mark Setchell, gave me the best solution ever, please read the right answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getbbox()` to get the bounding box:

```
image=Image.open('text.jpg') 
x1,y1,x2,y2=image.getbbox() 
print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

**Output**

```
16 192 208 216
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution ever, Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can a deep learning based model "EAST" to detect text on images. OpenCV’s EAST text detector is based on a novel architecture and training pattern. It is capable of

(1) running at near real-time at 13 FPS on 720p images and

(2) obtains state-of-the-art text detection accuracy.See this link for reference: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/.